# What is the best method for reverse voltage protection of a microcontroller

Tags: diodes, circuit-design, schottky

When connecting a USB to TTL cable to flash a microcontroller (ESP32), I want to provide reverse voltage protection because connecting the pins in the wrong direction is easy to do and will destroy the processor.

The USB to TTL cable outputs 3.3V and the ESP32 needs at least 3V to function, so the voltage drops needs to be very small. The ESP32 also requires up to 500mA of current.

I am not sure if using a diode or using a MOSFET is the best method of protection for this low voltage application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This circuit should do what you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn7GUH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't have the ability to put a series element on the negative branch, you can also implement a similar circuit using a P-FET on the positive branch instead.

N-FETs are preferable because they have lower RDSon for a given size and are also much more common parts than P-FETs.

Comment: The FET must be logic level for 3.3V, else the current flow will be very limited.

Comment: @JackCreasey MOSFETs are 2 quadrant devices - meaning in this case that as long as the gat is positive relative to the source it will conduct with either Vds polarity. This is aken adbantage of here by reversing the FETS normal ds polarity so that the body diode conducts when the battery if of correct polarity. This is swamped by the FET being turned on when the polarity is correct. When the battery is of incorrect polarity the FET is turned off AND the body diode does not conduct. | I have used this circuit successfully in several hundred thousand solar l

Comment: lights where the use of a series protection  diode would have caused excessive power loss.[3 s NimH = 3V to 3.6V. Series diode at 0.6V = 16 to 20 % power loss

Answer (score 0):

Panasonic in their cordless telephones use a parallel 1n4001 diode. With reverse voltage it short-circuits the supply and heats up the diode, when the diode starts to smoke it indicates to the user that the polarity is incorrect!

I've done this a few times and so far I've never lost a cordless phone to this abuse, the phone works once the correct power supply is connected. (Panasonic use centre negative on their plugs, everyone else seems to use the opposite polarity)

I woudn't expect such a setup to survive connecton to a lead-acid battery, but connecting a powersupply of 1-2A capacity hasn't destroyed any phones or power-supplies yet.

Comment: that's hard core ;^)

Comment: And if you add a fuse before the diode, the solution doesn't involve the magic smoke, just a broken fuse. I think that's the best solution.

Comment: there's plenty of smoke in a 1N4001,  using a fuse would render the device inoperable = warranty return = cost,  a polyswitch could work I guess.